# Join Oracle tables on an exact match, and a closest match

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to join two tables of performance metrics, system stats and memory usage. Entries in these tables come in on differing time schedules. I need to join the tables by finding the exact match for the System_Name in both tables, and the closest for WRITETIME. Write time uses the systems own idea of time and is NOT a standard Oracle timestamp.

I can select the closest timestamp from one table with something like:

```
select "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME", ABS ('1140408134015004' - "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME") 
  as Diff from "Unix_Memory" 
  where "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" > '1140408104015004' order by Diff;
```

The constants there will be parameterised in my script.

However when I try to expand this into my larger query:

```
select "System"."System_Name", "System"."WRITETIME" as SysStamp,
from "System" 
join "Unix_Memory"  on "System"."System_Name" = "Unix_Memory"."System_Name" 
and "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" = ( 
select Stamp from (
select "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" as Stamp, 
ABS ( "System"."WRITETIME" - "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME") as Diff 
  from "Unix_Memory" where "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" > '1140408104015004' and rownum = 1 order by Diff
  )
)
WHERE "System"."System_Name" in ('this','that', 'more')
and   "System"."WRITETIME"  > '1140408124015004';
```

I get:

```
Error at Command Line:38 Column:72
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "System"."WRITETIME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I have tried a few variations, but I am not getting any closer.

Comment: does `SELECT "SYSTEM"."WRITETIME" FROM "SYSTEM"` work?

Comment: no but `SELECT "System"."WRITETIME" FROM "System";` Does

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the column names are only known in the next nesting level. So System.writetime would be known in `select Stamp from ...`, but no more in `select "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" as Stamp ...`

Anyhow, you would select a rather random stamp anyhow, the first Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" > '1140408104015004' found to be precise, because rownum = 1 gets executed before order by. You will have to re-write your statement completely.

EDIT: Here is one possibility to re-write the statement using MIN/MAX KEEP:

```
select 
  s.system_name, 
  s.writetime as sysstamp,
  min(um.id) keep (dense_rank first order by abs(s.writetime - um.writetime)) as closest_um_id
from system sys 
join unix_memory um  on s.system_name = um.system_name 
where s.system_name in ('this','that', 'more')
and s.writetime > '1140408124015004'
and um.writetime > '1140408104015004'
group by s.system_name, s.writetime
order by s.system_name, s.writetime;
```

If you need more than just the ID of unix_memory then surround this with another select:

```
select   
  sy.system_name, 
  sy.sysstamp,
  mem.*
from
(
  select 
    s.system_name, 
    s.writetime as sysstamp,
    min(um.id) keep (dense_rank first order by abs(s.writetime - um.writetime)) as closest_um_id
  from system sys 
  join unix_memory um  on s.system_name = um.system_name 
  where s.system_name in ('this','that', 'more')
  and s.writetime > '1140408124015004'
  and um.writetime > '1140408104015004'
  group by s.system_name, s.writetime
) sy
join unix_memory mem on mem.id = sy.closest_um_id
order by sy.system_name, sy.sysstamp;
```

Comment: What is the best way to do that re-order then. Should I do the inner select and order by, and wrap it in another select with rownum=1? Or is there a better way to go about what I am doing? Conceptually I just need to get an exact match on System_Name, and the closest match on the WRITETIME from the second table.

Comment: Thorsten, thank you, using the second version, it now does exactly what I need. One more question. I use this to produce an aggregate load factor based on stats from System and Memory tables. My boss, now asked if I can make it a view for charting. When I remove the `Writetime > nnn` Constraints and create a view, it takes ~forever to select on the view. I guess it is comparing all writetimes through the table. Is there a way to limit the writetime match, to only look at writeimes from the memory table within, say half an hour of the time from the system table? FWIW Writetime is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You must state the System table in the inner Select as well.

```
select "System"."System_Name", "System"."WRITETIME" as SysStamp,
from "System" 
join "Unix_Memory"  on "System"."System_Name" = "Unix_Memory"."System_Name" 
and "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" = ( 
select Stamp from (
select "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" as Stamp, 
ABS ( "System"."WRITETIME" - "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME") as Diff 
  from "Unix_Memory" 
  -- THE NEXT LINE IS MISSING IN YOUR CODE
  INNER JOIN "System" ON "System.System_Name" = "Unix_Memory"."System_Name"
                     and "System"."WRITETIME"  > '1140408124015004'
  -- end of missing
  where "Unix_Memory"."WRITETIME" > '1140408104015004' and rownum = 1 order by Diff
  )
)
WHERE "System"."System_Name" in ('this','that', 'more')
and   "System"."WRITETIME"  > '1140408124015004';
```